# what is difference between currentAuthenticatedUser() and currentUserPoolUser() in AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have read the `AWS Amplify API` and I have found some weird thing.

I've found 2 similar functions

`currentAuthenticatedUser()` and `currentUserPoolUser()`.

They have the same description, parameters, and returns.

I want to know why they separated.

[reference]

https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html#currentauthenticateduser

https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html#currentuserpooluser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe user pool users are those that are from Cognito, whereas an authenticated user is one that come from an identity pool (from a federated identity).

See: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pools-identity-pools/

Comment: but they are 100% the same without the function name.

Comment: They follow the same schema (SAML 2.0) but this seperated federated users from cognito user pool users

Comment: Could you explain which function should I use for `log in`?

Comment: It depends where your user base come from

Answer (score 1):

From the [code](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/a047ce73/packages/auth/src/Auth.ts#L1191), it looks like currentAuthenticatedUser checks for federation info. However, if it doesn't find federation info, it just calls currentUserPoolUser. So I'd say call currentUserPoolUser if you know you're never going to be using federated logins, but you should probably call currentAuthenticatedUser if there's a chance you might.

Answer (score 0):

according to amplify [auth docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html#currentauthenticateduser), both result in "A promise resolves to current authenticated CognitoUser if success"